# React get HTMLElement properties from ref to a custom component

Tags: reactjs

Getting HTML properties from a ref to a DOM element is pretty straightforward.

```
<div ref={element => this.myDiv = element}>
  <h1>Bla bla</h1>
</div>

...

componentDidMount() => {
  console.log(this.myDiv.clientHeight); // Gives desired result
}
```

However, how do you do the same with a ref to a custom component?

```
<CustomElement ref={element => this.myDiv = element}>
  <h1>Bla bla</h1>
</CustomElement>

...

componentDidMount() => {
  console.log(this.myDiv.clientHeight); // Undefined
}
```

Console logging the whole ref object isn't helpful either. All I retrieve from that is an object with state, props, ref, and updater as properties, but the DOM specific properties are nowhere to be found.

Comment: do you found any solution for this? i have the same problem. I have a custom element of X type but useref returns an element of type HTMLElement and i can't access the cusom element properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it isn't rendered to the DOM. How can you get DOM properties on something that isn't rendered to the DOM? You will need to get a ref to an actual HTML element that is rendered by that react component if you want to get the DOM properties.

I would use a div or some html element as the top level element in your render function and get a ref to that.